# Why is PROJ4/cs2cs reprojection latlon to lcc NAD83 generating sys errno:2

Tags: python, proj

I am trying to use PROJ4/cs2cs to change the projection of latlon coordinates from latlon to lcc. 
I have the NAD83/NAD27 in the proj/nad directory and have rebuilt and installed PROJ.

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this sys errno message when I try to run the following code?

```
cs2cs +proj=latlon +datum=WGS84 +to +proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-95   +x_0=0 +y_0=0 datum=NAD83 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ifile.txt | tee ofile.txt
Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012
<cs2cs>:
Sys errno: 2: <system mess. texts unavail.>
datum=NAD83
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot '+' in front of 'datum' command ;)

`datum=NAD83` -> `+datum=NAD83`